# Coloring a specific value in a axis in a Plot

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to Plot a function, and the a specific value in the y-axis. For example, I would like y=1.5 on the y axis to be red. Is this possible?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

For example, how could I do with a simple Sin[x] function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want this:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {-1, -0.5, {0.5, Style["0.5", Red, 12]}, 1}}]
```

[image]

??

Comment: Yes! Thank you.